# Group By Sku, Merge Data - String Aggregation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't think of the best way to tackle this in access. One thing to note. There are probably 15 other fields as well but they should all be duplicate data, just like sku.

```
Original
    Sku    |    Category
    Apple  |    Fruit
    Apple  |    Consumable

Need
    Sku    |    Category
    Apple  |    Fruit,Consumable
```

After insight from comments below I was able to make this work

```
SELECT [rg test].PROD_CODE, DConcat("PRODREPGDE","[rg test]","[PROD_CODE] = '" & [PROD_CODE] & "'") AS [Reporting Group]
FROM [rg test]
GROUP BY [rg test].prod_code;
```

Comment: This is commonly known as "String Aggregation". Access doesn't have a built in function for this, but some smart folks have built UDFs to do the job. [Check out this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98089/how-to-get-the-equivalent-of-array-or-string-group-by-aggregate-functions-in-acc) on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Indeed, you will have to use application code above SQL such as VBA to produce desired output. Do note: Access SQL does have the dynamic crosstab query to output pivoted result but in distinct columns (not comma-separated values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After insight from comments below I was able to make this work

```
SELECT [rg test].PROD_CODE, DConcat("PRODREPGDE","[rg test]","[PROD_CODE] = '"    & [PROD_CODE] & "'") AS [Reporting Group]
FROM [rg test]
GROUP BY [rg test].prod_code;
```